# A function of a list of, say, 100 cities, and we want the FURTHEST point in the Continental US

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I haven't given up on this problem but not being fluent in the Mathematica Wolfram Language, mainly because I don't know the commands.
Tia

Comment: Do you mean the point on the border of the continental US that is furthest from the city?

Comment: Furthest-point queries are hard. One approach might be to use a level set method such as fast marching.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the answer to my comment is yes, here is one way to do it

```
polygonUS = Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]["Polygon"];
borderPoints = polygonUS[[1, 1, 1]] // Map[GeoPosition];

furthestFrom[city_, borderPoints_] := 
  AssociationThread[borderPoints -> Normal@GeoDistance[borderPoints, city]] //
  ReverseSort // Take[#, 1] &

london = Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}];
furthest = furthestFrom[london,borderPoints]
```

> ```
> <|GeoPosition[{32.5343, -117.124}] -> Quantity[5504.35, "Miles"]|>
> ```

```
furthestPosition = First@Keys@furthest;
furthestCities = GeoNearest["City", furthestPosition, 2]
```

> ```
> {Entity["City", {"ImperialBeach", "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
>  Entity["City", {"SanDiego", "California", "UnitedStates"}]}
> ```

```
GeoGraphics[{Red, GeoPath[{city, furthestPosition}, "Geodesic"]}, 
 GeoRange -> {{10, 70}, {-120, 10}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I continued to fiddle around and came up with this,  San Francisco is just an example.  In this case, it looks like Mahchester, NH is the furthest to San Francisco.

```
cityCenter = Interpreter["City"]["San Francisco"]
cities = CityData[{Large, "United States"}];
table1 = Table[{cities[[k]], 
    QuantityMagnitude[TravelDistance[cities[[k]], cityCenter]]}, {k, 
    Length[cities]}];
First[Sort[table1, #1[[2]] >=  #2[[2]] &]]
```

Comment: `TravelDistance` uses `Driving` as the default `TravelMethod`. That distance can be significantly different from the geodesic distance.